# Wrong layout used on first load after switching to/from mobile version of application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, mobile

I have 2 application layouts: application.html.haml and application.mobile.haml. But when I switch from mobile to the non-mobile version the mobile layout is still used for the first load. In Firebug console I see that the non-mobile view was properly returned, however the browser and the Firebug HTML tab show the mobile layout. Any idea what's going? It's fine after a refresh.

Comment: Do you have a link for us, otherwise it's esoteric guesswork.

Comment: esoteric guesswork : clear your cache between each load.

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be caused by JQuery Mobile.

I found the answer here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a3/docs/pages/docs-pages.html

JQuery Mobile doesn't do full page reloads unless it's told to, so although the full html was returned, JQuery Mobile just replaced the page portion.

The key portion from the docs is:
"It's important to note if you are linking from a mobile page that was loaded via Ajax to a page with multiple internal pages, you need to add a rel="external" or data-ajax="false" to the link. This tells the framework to do a full page reload to clear out the Ajax hash in the URL. This is critical because Ajax pages use the hash (#) to track the Ajax history, while multiple internal pages use the hash to indicate internal pages so there will be a conflicts."

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I encountered a similar problem.

In my case, Rails4's [turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks) suffered. Similarly as JQuery Mobile, turbolinks only updates the body part of a full page without updating the head part of the html when an intra-site link is clicked. I simply removed the require line for turbolinks in my application.js and the problem disappeared.